# See on invoices which items are sold together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, invoice

I am working with ***python***.

I am working with ***csv***.

I am working with ***pandas.DataFrame***.

I have like 1.000.000 invoices.

The invoices have the following format:

***Invoice 1:***

- ***Pear***
- apple
- orange

***Invoice 2:***

- kiwi
- tangerine
- pineapple

***Invoice 3:***

- melon
- ***Pear***
- watermelon

...

I want to get this:

***Pear***

is usually sold with:

- apple
- orange
- melon
  -watermelon

Any efficient way to get there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One million invoices in csv files?

Answer (score 0):

This is called market basket analysis.

Python package mlxtend.frequent_patterns can do this for you.

There are numerous articles that show you how to do this, below is one such useful one:
https://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html